# Openxml altchunk changing properties in end document

Tags: openxml, openxml-table

I am strugeling with openxml and the function altchunk.
I am using altchunk to merge several template Word document into a master document.
These Word documents contain text, pictures and tables.
It works for most of the templates to get merged, but for some few templates, the font size, font name and spacingbetweenlines always ends up with fontsize 11, Arial and spaceafter “8”

I haved tried to control it with paragraph, cellproperties, runproperties settings but nothing change.

All templates are created from the same clean master, with fontsize 10, Calibri, and spaceafter=”0”
I have analyzed the xml part of the end document, with Open XML SDK 2.5, to se where the bad settings are located, but there are no signs of Arial, size 11 or “8”
Also tests with StyleDefinitionsPart failed.
Any help will be much appreciated.